# AngularJS form validation not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble getting form validation to work correcty.

I have the following form:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name"
                placeholder="Enter a name for your topic discovery" required/>
    <p ng-show="testForm.name.$invalid" class="help-block">A name is reqiured for the topic discovery</p>
</form>
```

But the `<p>` element is never shown, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" ng-model="name"
       placeholder="Enter a name for your topic discovery" required />
```

Remember that element is registered under `testForm` namespace by it's *name*, not `ngModel`, in your case they are the same but in most cases they different.

Comment: Double check everything, that was your error, it should work. http://plnkr.co/edit/geMpz3ObYSaf79gc6u96?p=info

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add input name

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name"
                        placeholder="Enter a name for your topic discovery" required/>
```

full example:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="name"
                    placeholder="Enter a name for your topic discovery" required/>
        <p ng-show="testForm.name.$touched && testForm.name.$invalid" class="help-block">A name is reqiured for the topic discovery</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your type attribute value is "text", which is kind of hard to become invalid. Change it to "email" for example, then set value of name attribute to some "myName" (for visual difference) for your input element (as others suggested above). You could also add another condition to ng-show attribute of your `<p>` element like this:

```
<p ng-show="testForm.myName.$invalid && testForm.myName.$dirty" class="help-block">A name is reqiured for the topic discovery</p>
```

Comment: When the textbox is empty it has the class `form-control ng-dirty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required`